# Get all the words in a sentence to an Arrya, ignoring whitespaces?

Tags: java

I want to read all the words in a sentence, to a Array. The problem is, there can be any number of white spaces between the words.

```
Example - "I    am a good      boy".
```

I have tried to use, Split method with white space as delimiter, but It will include the white space too as in the result.

The code I have used for this is below. Please ignore, the rest of the code.

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         // c. Total the 100 elements of floating-point array c and print them.
        double c[] = new double [100];
        String str="BusNo 123    ArrivalTime 1030   Departure 1420  ";
        String split[]=str.split(" ");
        double total=0;
        //Initialize C with Random Numbers from 0 to 10,000 Randomly
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++){
            c[k]=Math.random() *10000;
            total+=c[k]; //Find the Total;
            System.out.printf("C is %f\n",c[k]);
        }
        System.out.printf("Total is %f\n", total);
    }
}
```

For my sample text as shown above, The split[] Array will be as follows

```
[I, , , , am, a, good, , , , , , boy]
```

I know, a workaround, that I can have a loop after my str.split( ) and ignore all the white spaces.

I would appreciate, if there is any better way to read directly without any spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) by [whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), not just a single space, so that multiple spaces is considered one single delimiter.

```
String split[] = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 3):

For spaces only, you can use

```
String[] strings = input.split("[ ]+");
```

or

```
String[] strings = input.split(" +");
```

For any whitespace (spaces, tabs, or new-lines), use

```
String[] strings = input.split("\\s+");
```